# "subject verb agreement" two subject connected using 'and', and it uses sigular verb

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, singular-vs-plural

I know that when two subjects are connected using "and", we need to use the plural form, as in:

> He and I are good friends.

Are there any exceptions? I am asking this because I came across this sentence:

> - He and my dad **believes** that mom is always right.

There is another kind of sentence like:

> Each boy and each girl  **has** submitted **his/her** form.

or

> Every boy and every girl  **has** submitted **his/her** form.

If I made any grammatical mistakes on the question, please mention it in the comments.

Comment: If there is  a comma, so that it is **He, and my dad, believes that mom is always right**, then your "reliable source" is correct.

Comment: @SiddharthaSadhukhan This particular video is full of terrible advice and incorrect usages. She is **completely wrong** about the cited usage, and I am sorry to tell you that Dinesh Miglani (or whoever is "teaching" in this video) is simply not qualified to teach English. Far from being reliable, she is doing a disservice to those who trust her.

Comment: @AlanCarmack are you sure?  I would say "He, and my dad, **believe**" because *they* both believe it.  The comma doesn't change anything.  The only way it would is if there was some information to indicate "my dad" isn't party to the belief, for example: "He *asked to my dad* and believes ..."  Or maybe that my dad does not believe, "He, *not my dad*, believes ..."

Comment: @Andrew My statement is an application of Quirk, et al., *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language.* p 761 on "Quasi-coordination', in which the authors state that with such 'quasi-coordinators' as *along with*, *as well as*, (*in addition to*), the verb is singular if the first noun phrase is singular. So, if *and my dad* is read as *in addition to my dad*, then *He, and my dad, believes that....* is parallel to *He, along with/in addition to/as well as my dad, believes that...*

Comment: @Andrew (continued) Quirk et al. give the example: *The captain, as well as the other players, was tired*. Per me, if the *and my dad* is read as parenthetical information, then yes, *believes* is fine.

Comment: @AlanCarmack Without additional information I read the *and* to mean *both* rather than *also*.  But I can see how your example works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sentence is grammatically correct because it's a plural conjugation (**we are** can replace "He and I")

"Is there any exceptions? " - **Are** there any exceptions.

The second sentence is not grammatically correct (he and my dad believes) because the subject is plural ("we believe"), so you must use plural conjugation (see above).

The third sentence uses the counter /each/, which must be used with a singluar noun, and therefore the conjugation should be singular (each + noun + is). This is idiomatic/ an exception.

The fourth sentence is singular for the same reason. /Every/ is used with singular nouns and treated like a singluar countable noun. This includes the group noun /everybody/ (everybody **is**).

Some nouns in English require singular conjugation, even in plural e.g. /everybody/ is
BUT most follow the rule and these are not common. Memorise the exceptions!

Comment: from a reliable source I found "He and my dad believes that mom is always right.", which suppose to be right. Where it get stuck

Comment: It's wrong. Just remember "He and my dad" can be replaced with "they", so the verb should agree with "they". The mistake you have shown is often made because people see "my dad" and want to make the verb agree with that.

Comment: @SiddharthaSadhukhan Please see my comment above. This source is **not** reliable. Unfortunately, anyone at all can make a video and post it on YouTube. If you can, you should try to study with a native speaker of English.

Comment: I am a native speaker and I will be happy to answer any questions.

Comment: @TomB There are scores of native speakers here, of course, and your answer above is fine—I just want to be sure that the OP comes away with an informed skepticism about such "teachers" as the one in the video cited in his question.